# Probability of withdrawing a card with or without replacement

Tags: probability, card-games

The traditional deck features suits in red (diamonds and hearts) and black (clubs and
spades), what is the approximate probability

a. that the card drawn is a seven or a red suit card?

b. of drawing a seven, returning it to the deck and right after pulling a red suit card?

c. of drawing a seven and then a red card without replacing the first card?

a. The probability is given by $\dfrac{4}{52} + \dfrac{26}{52} - \dfrac{2}{52} = 0,53$

b. $\dfrac{1}{13} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{26}$

Are my calculations in a and b correct? I can't see any difference between calculating b and c.

Comment: In $b$ the two events are independent.  In $c$ they appear to be dependent (in that you either removed a black card or a red card and thereby changed the distribution in the surviving deck).

Comment: You are right. The probability should still be the same. May be they want you to show how or give a justification.

Comment: A slightly more basic variant of this was something my probability students found surprising: Show that the probability of drawing a particular card, say the queen of spades, is the same whether it's a complete deck or whether it's a deck with one card already removed at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b & c are different scenarios, but you get the same answer, still. b states that you need to find the probability of 'drawing a seven, returning it to the deck and right after pulling a red suit card?'. That means you need to find the probability of drawing a 7 from 52 cards, which is $\frac4{52}$. Now, you need to put the card you drew back into the pile, leaving it with 52 cards again. Now find the probability of drawing a red card. There are 2 colors, red and black, each with equal probability, so this is equal to $\frac12$. Now multiply the probabilities you got. $\frac4{52}$ * $\frac12$ = $\frac1{26}$. So that is the answer to b.

c is very similar, but after you draw the seven, you don't put the 7 back in the pile, so there are only 51 cards left. Now we split this up into 2 cases. If the 7 is red, there is a $\frac2{52}$ chance to draw it. Since we drew a red seven, there are 25 reds to draw out of the remaining 51 cards, so the chance of drawing a red card after drawing a red 7 is $\frac{25}{51}$. Now multiply the probabilities $\frac2{52}$ * $\frac{25}{51}$ = $\frac{25}{1326}$. The second case is that the 7 we drew was black, a chance of $\frac2{52}$. This leaves 26 red cards out of 51 left to draw, so the chance of drawing a red is now $\frac{26}{51}$. Multiply the probabilities to get $\frac2{52}$ * $\frac{26}{51}$ = $\frac1{51}$. Now add the probabilities of both cases to get $\frac{25}{1326}$ + $\frac1{51}$ = $\frac{1}{26}$.

Comment: This is not correct. The deck has $26$ red and $26$ black so you are left with either $26$ red or $25$ red which add up to $51$ so the probability remains as $1/26$.

Comment: I do not understand, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: How many red in $51$ cards? Your working says $13/51$ in case you drew the first one as black. If you fix that, you will see the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, ok I see now, I fixed it, I still don't understand why they are the same probability though.

Comment: Oh, actually I got it, thank you